# Add additional selector for click event in (Vue v2.5.16)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have problem with events in my vue app.
I want to listen to events like that:

```
<div class="element" @click="elementClicked" >
    <div class="childClass"></div>
    <div class="anotherOne"></div>
    // etc.
</div>
```

However I want to add additional selector, like I used to do in jquery:

```
$('.element').on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    ...
}])
```

And I cannot bind specific elements, because this is part of code I'm loading by ajax (buttons in datatable)

There is any good solution?

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with addEventListener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Also, how are you rendering the buttons? do you use `v-for` or do you mutate the DOM directly?

Comment: I can use addEventListener, but I have been wondering if there is something dedicated for it in vue. I'm using datatables.net to render it.

Comment: I don't think there is, The only way Vue can bind events is if Vue is rendering that markup. In your case, it looks like you are using datatables.net which is a jQuery plugin??. Anyway, it should be fairly safe and easy to use `addEventListener`